# Is there a fixed number to make any number even?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I there a fixed number that if we add it to any number it would always make it even? So if the number is even when adding it to the fixed number it would stay even and if we add it to an odd number it would make it even.
Is this possible?

Comment: If you subtract that proposed number from an even number, would you get an even or an odd number?

Comment: $\bmod n\!:\ a + x\equiv 0\Rightarrow x\equiv -a,\,$ i.e. the congruence has a *unique* solution, so it can't have all $\,n\,$ residues $\bmod n\,$ as solutions for $\,x\,$ (by $\,n \neq 1).\,$ For modulus $\,n=2\,$ we have $\,\color{#c00}{x\equiv -a\equiv a}\pmod{\!2},\,$ i.e. only adding integers of $\rm\color{#c00}{equal\ parity}$ yields an even integer. $\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is such a number then adding it to $1-x$ gives an even result.  But this means that $1$ is even, which it isn't.  So there is no such number.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. Here's a simple proof by contradiction as to why this is the case.

Let's assume that such a fixed number exists, and that the number is $K$. By definition of this number $K$, both $K+X$ and $K+(X+1)$ will be even for all integers $X$. But it is impossible for two consecutive integers to have the same parity, leading to a contradiction.

Because the assumption of the existence of such a number $K$ resulted in a contradiction, $K$ cannot possibly exist.

Answer (score 0):

I can prove that there **can not exist** such a number. Suppose the contrary that there does exist such a number say $x$. Let $p$ be an odd number and $q$ be an even number. According to your claim if we add $x$ with $p$ then $p+x$ would be even and if we add $x$ with $q$ then $x+q$ is also be even. But here is the problem. $x+p=even\implies x=even-p$, which shows that $x$ is odd. On the other hand, $x+q=even\implies x=even-q$ shows $x$ is even. How can $x$ be both even and odd at the same time? This gives a contradiction. Thus our assumption "*Such a number exists*" is wrong.

But if you ask if there is some function that can do that, YES. Define $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ as $$f(n)=n+1,\ \forall n\in\mathbb N.$$ Then it will do the work.

Comment: We had the same idea of proof by contradiction lol.

Answer (score 0):

No, this number does not exist.

Let's imagine we have such a number, and we'll call it $n$.

We know that any even number is two times another whole number, so we can write it as $e=2k$.

We want $e + n$ to be even, so we need $n$ to be divisible by $2$. Let's say $n = 2m$, so $e + n = 2k + 2m = 2(k+m)$, and so $e + n$ is even.

We also know that any odd number is one more than an even number, so we can write it as $o = 2k + 1$.

We want $o + n$ to be even, but $o + n = 2k + 2m + 1 = 2(k + m) + 1$!

This means that if our number added to an even number gives an even number, then it can't give an even number when you add it to an odd number.